# cx-Freeze w/ multiple exe using same libraries

Tags: python, compiler-errors, cx-freeze

I have 3 py files to compile using cx-Freeze. The compile is successful but it appears something is overwritten at each step, meaning only the last compile is functioning properly (3/3). Doing the first 2 one-by-one, the error does not appear and they function as expected. All 3 scripts are sharing some of the libraries. What am I missing?

> File
>   "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts__startup__.py",
>   line 13, in run
>       module = **import**(name + "**init**") ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scriptName__init__'

setup.py:

```
buildOptions = dict(excludes = ['matplotlib', 'PyQt4', 'PySide2'],
                    includes = ['urllib3', 'ibapi', 'idna.idnadata', 'numpy.core._methods', 'pandas'],
                    optimize = 1,
                    packages = ['pkg_resources._vendor'],
                )

for fName in glob.glob('*.py')[:-1]:
    nameDesc = fName.split('.')[0]
    setup(
        name = nameDesc,
        version = "0.1",
        description = nameDesc,
        executables = [Executable(script = fName)],
        options = dict(build_exe = buildOptions)
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
setup(
    name = 'Proj',
    version = '0.1',
    description = 'Proj',
    executables = [Executable(i) for i in glob.glob('*.py')],
    options = dict(build_exe = buildOptions),
)
```